# Cannot run a job to update table on a linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, jobs

I am running SQL Server 2012 on a server (server 1) and have set up a job to run a stored procedure which will summarize data from a series of tables and update a table on a linked server (server 2) which is also SQL Server 2012. I can successfully run the stored procedure on it's own, but when the scheduled job runs, I get the following error:

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "222.222.222.222" reported an error. Authentication failed.
>   [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7399)  Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "222.222.222.222".
>   [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7303)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "222.222.222.222" returned message "Invalid authorization specification".
>   [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412).  The step failed.,00:00:00,16,7412,,,,0

I suspect this is a security issue, but cannot find the settings that will let me run this.

Comment: Check which account the SQL Server Agent Service is running under (using SQL Server Configuration Manager on the server).

Comment: And check how security is set up under Server Objects > Linked Servers > right-click 222.222.222.222

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server 2012 builds that were released after SQL Server 2012 was released. You must apply a SQL Server 2012 hotfix to an installation of SQL Server 2012. The fix for this issue was released in Cumulative Update 1 for SQL Server 2012.  For more detail please read:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2652582/fix-invalid-authorization-specification-error-message-when-you-run-the

Answer (score -2):

Include the local login "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
[image]

Comment: Doing that will allow any remote service running as the Network Service account on the same domain to run anything including a `DROP DATABASE` command against the linked server.  I would highly recommend not adding the `NT AUTHORITY\Network Service` to your SQL Server like this.